# Divide elasticsearch query result into chunks?

Tags: python, python-2.7, elasticsearch

I have an elasticsearch query like this, this query would yield around 25k results, so how can I divide the delivery of my result into chunks, say 5000 results per time so it would not hurt the server memory?

```
def get_data():
    totals = 0
    payload = { 

      "size": 50000,
          "query": {
              "filtered": {  
                "filter" : {
                  "bool": {
                    "must": [
                      {"term": {"events.id": "1"}},
                      {"range": {"score_content_0": {"gte": 60}} },
                      {"range": {"published_at": { "gte": "2016-12-19T00:00:00", "lte": "2017-04-19T23:59:59"}}},
                      {"term": {"lang": "en"}}

            ]
          }
         }
        }
        }  
    }

    r = requests.post(RM_URL, json=payload)
    results = json.loads(r.content, encoding='utf-8')
    totals = results['hits']['total']
    myhits = results['hits']['hits']
    return myhits
```

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately you can't get more than 10000 results at a time. And you can't even paginate past this point, so if you really want to get 25k results you would need to use scan API.

Just to clarify: I'm talking about `elasticsearch 5.x` (and maybe `2.4`) in early versions it is possible

Comment: hi, I actually ran it on my company's server and retrieved 25k at once, the data engineer guys told me I should divide my query result into chunks to reduce pressures for server memory, may you assist me on how to use the scan API with python?

Comment: That may help: https://elasticsearch-py.readthedocs.io/en/master/helpers.html#scan